# Spring MVC 4.0.0.5, Maven, and Quartz

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I have been trying to get quartz to work on this web app that we are creating and havne't been able to.  I've tried 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.1.4.. I just don't know what to do anymore, none of them want to build correctly.  I'm pretty sure that I am doing everything else correctly.  I just really need some help figuring this one out.  I'm not doing anything fancy with it yet, I just want it to run for now!  I put my files below.

POM file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

spring-quartz.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <bean id="QuartzService" class="org.webapp.service.QuartzService" />

   <bean id="myJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
          <property name="targetObject" ref="QuartzService" />
          <property name="targetMothod" value="printCurrentTime" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
          <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJob" />
          <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />
          <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />
   </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" >
         <property name="jobDetails">
                 <list>
                        <ref bean="myJob" />
                 </list>
          </property>
          <property name="triggers">
                 <list>
                        <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
                 </list>
          </property>
   </bean>
```

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class QuartzController {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-quartz.xml");
    }
}
```

Service:

```
import org.webapp.repository.QuartzRepository;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;

public class QuartzService extends QuartzJobBean{
    private QuartzRepository myTask;

    public void setMyTask(QuartzRepository myTask){
        this.myTask = myTask;
    }

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        myTask.printCurrentTime();
    }
}
```

Repo Class:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class QuartzRepository {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("repository");

    public void printCurrentTime() {
        logger.error("BITCH: " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that is everything.  The error that I keep getting is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/src/main/java/org/webapp/service/QuartzService.java:[9,45] package org.springframework.scheduling.quartz does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/src/main/java/org/webapp/service/QuartzService.java:[11,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class QuartzJobBean
[ERROR] /C:/src/main/java/org/webapp/service/QuartzService.java:[18,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:858)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: After removing expletives from your code, you might look up what artifact that class is supposed to be in (I'm quite confident it's not in the core Quartz dependency).

Answer (score 8):

You have to add "spring-context-support" as dependency, not only "spring-context"

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven is not able to find package **org.springframework.scheduling.quartz** during compilation phase. I think you have added the spring dependencies not with the help of maven. Your pom is only having quartz. Try to add spring dependencies through **pom**. I think it will work.